# R data frame. Check and subtract with step

Tags: r

I have got the following data frame:

[image]

Code:

```
name <- c("A","A","A","B")
a <- c (1,2,3,4)
b <- c (5, 6, 7, 8)

df <- data.frame(name,a,b)
```

What I am trying to do is to replicate excel steps.

If name in row 2 == name in row 1 then 6 - 1

If name in row 3 == name in row 2 then 7 - 2

If name in row 4 == name in row 3 the nothing as B <> A.

So the desired result would be:

[image]

Comment: What is your expected output?  What are the rules if there are more rows

Comment: First check if subsequent name is the same and then do subtraction as another column.

Comment: Something like `df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(new = lead(b)-a)`

Comment: But I can not change the order for the data.

Comment: Please show your expected output.  It is not clear to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(name) %>%
   mutate(new = lag(lead(b)-a))
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   name [2]
#  name      a     b   new
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         1     5     NA
#2 A         2     6     5
#3 A         3     7     5
#4 B         4     8    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(name) %>% mutate(result = b- lag(a))

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups: name [2]
#  name      a     b result
#  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A      1.00  5.00 NA   
#2 A      2.00  6.00  5.00
#3 A      3.00  7.00  5.00
#4 B      4.00  8.00 NA
```